# Based in a character, how to separate in new rows each cell of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe like [this](https://pastebin.com/bBaTPvc2) (this is the data):

In:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/user/Desktop/example.csv', sep = '|')
df
```

Out:

```
    ColA   ColB
0   Lemons  NaN
1   Oranges https://www.example.com#fruitN : title: Click ...
2   Tomatos NaN
```

In

```
df['ColB'][1]
```

Out:

```
'https://www.example.com#fruitN : title: Click here to show   https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=200465 : title: Click to view ORANGES OK AND TOMATOES FRESH (ORANGES OK; TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #200465 : 12 Pz : TRUE : COMPANY_5    https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=203874 : title: Click to view ORANGES OK AND TOMATOES FRESH (ORANGES OK; TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #203874 : 12 Pz : TRUE : COMPANY_1    https://www.example.com#fruitName : title: Click here to show   https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=076477 : title: Click to view TOMATOES FRESH (TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #076477 : 12 Pz : TRUE : Company_7    https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=077575 : title: Click to view TOMATOES FRESH (TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #077575 : 12 Pz : TRUE : COMPANY_2    https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=6538773 : title: Click to view TOMATOES FRESH (TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #6538773 : 12 Pz : Discontinued : COMPANY_3    https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=090548 : title: Click to view TOMATOES FRESH (TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #090548 : 12 Pz : TRUE : COMPANY_4    https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=091226 : title: Click to view TOMATOES FRESH (TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #091226 : 12 Pz : TRUE : COMPANY_5    https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=091624 : title: Click to view TOMATOES FRESH (TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #091624 : 12 Pz : TRUE : COMPANY_6    https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=091650 : title: Click to view TOMATOES FRESH (TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #091650 : 12 Pz : TRUE : COMPANY_1    '
```

Each cell in `ColB` has a newline character (/`\n`). How can I expand in rows (with out losing it's name `ColA` reference string) each line separated by it's new line character?. Something like this:

```
ColA    | ColB
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lemons  | NaN
Oranges | https://www.example.com#fruitN : title: Click here to show
Oranges | https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=200465 : title: Click to view ORANGES OK AND TOMATOES FRESH (ORANGES OK; TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #200465 : 12 Pz : TRUE : COMPANY_5    
Oranges | https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=203874 : title: Click to view ORANGES OK AND TOMATOES FRESH (ORANGES OK; TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #203874 : 12 Pz : TRUE : COMPANY_1    
Oranges | https://www.example.com#FruitName : title: Click here to show   
Oranges | https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=076477 : title: Click to view TOMATOES FRESH (TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #076477 : 12 Pz : TRUE : Company_7    
Oranges | https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=077575 : title: Click to view TOMATOES FRESH (TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #077575 : 12 Pz : TRUE : COMPANY_2    
Oranges | https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=6538773 : title: Click to view TOMATOES FRESH (TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #6538773 : 12 Pz : Discontinued : COMPANY_3    
Oranges | https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=090548 : title: Click to view TOMATOES FRESH (TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #090548 : 12 Pz : TRUE : COMPANY_4    
Oranges | https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=091226 : title: Click to view TOMATOES FRESH (TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #091226 : 12 Pz : TRUE : COMPANY_5    
Oranges | https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=091624 : title: Click to view TOMATOES FRESH (TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #091624 : 12 Pz : TRUE : COMPANY_6    
Oranges | https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=overview.proc&ApplNo=091650 : title: Click to view TOMATOES FRESH (TOMATOES FRESH) : ID  #091650 : 12 Pz : TRUE : COMPANY_1
Tomatoes| NaN
```

I tried to:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.ColA.tolist(), index=df.ColB).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='ColB')[['ColA','ColB']]
```

And:

```
df['ColB'] = df['ColB'].str.extract('\b\n\b', expand=True)
df
```

**UPDATE**

After trying Abdou's approach I got the same:

In:

```
df1 = df.ColB.astype(str).str.split('\n(?=http)', expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1).to_frame()
df2 = df1.merge(df[['ColA']], how='left', right_index=True, left_index = True)
df2.columns = ['ColB', 'ColA']
print(df2[['ColA','ColB']])
```

Out:

```
          ColA                                               ColB
0       Lemons                                                nan
1  Oranges.txt  https://www.example.com#fruitN : title: Click ...
2  Tomatos.txt                                                nan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `.str.split` method on `ColB` and expanding the result into a dataframe, which you can in turn merge back to the main dataframe:

```
df1 = df.ColB.astype(str).str.split('\n(?=http)', expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1).to_frame()

df2 = df1.merge(df[['ColA']], how='left', right_index=True, left_index = True)

df2.columns = ['ColB', 'ColA']

print(df2[['ColA','ColB']])

#       ColA                                               ColB
# 0   Lemons                                                nan
# 1  Oranges  https://www.example.com#fruitN : title: Click ...
# 1  Oranges  https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=o...
# 1  Oranges  https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=o...
# 1  Oranges  https://www.example.com/#FruitName2 : tit...
# 1  Oranges  https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=o...
# 1  Oranges  https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=o...
# 1  Oranges  https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=o...
# 1  Oranges  https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=o...
# 1  Oranges  https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=o...
# 1  Oranges  https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=o...
# 1  Oranges  https://www.example.com/ceuerindex.cfm?event=o...
# 2  Tomatos                                                nan
```

Please note that the pattern used to split the values is my own interpretation of how I would go about splitting. You can modify it to match your desired pattern.

#### Edit:

As stated above, the pattern you use to split is very important here. From your example data, it looks like values are separated by whitespaces, and not newline characters. So perhaps, you can get `df1` with the following, instead:

```
df1 = df.ColB.astype(str).str.split('\s(?=http)', expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1).to_frame()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help!... However I got: `          ColA                                               ColB
0       Lemons                                                nan
1  Oranges.txt  https://www.example.com#fruitN : title: Click ...
2  Tomatos.txt ` The same result... Nothing changed and the dataframe did not reformated...

Comment: `          ColA                                               ColB
0       Lemons                                                nan
1  Oranges.txt  https://www.example.com#fruitN : title: Click ...
2  Tomatos.txt   `

Comment: Thanks for the help!